# HashMap of Type <List <K>, List<V>> won't accept <List<K>, List<String>>

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have the following hashmap:

```
public  Map<List<K>, List<V>> m= new HashMap<List<K>, List<V>>();
```

I have a string of values `String vStr= "Hello, Hi";`. I would like to put those values in the map.

What is the best way of putting `vStr` in the map `m`?

The first step I take is `String[] values = vStr.split(",");`

where allKeys is `K allKeys = (K) "Hej";`

However, when I try to insert the above into the map so:

```
m.put(Arrays.asList(allKeys),Arrays.asList(values));
```

I get the error

```
The method put(List<K>, List<V>) in the type Map<List<K>,List<V>> is not applicable for the arguments (List<K>, List<String>)
```

Is there a way of not having to cast `List<String>` to `List<V>` ? If I have to is there a standard & good way of doing this?

Comment: try this `public  Map<List<?>, List<?>> m= new HashMap<List<?>, List<?>>();`

Comment: @codingmonster wow! thank you, that solved the issue. I did not think of using the wildcard.

Comment: :) I haven't tested it because i 've no environment for test. Isn't there any errors? Or I'm very lucky.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me, why use generics if you're enforcing strings?

Comment: While using wildcard types might eliminate the compile error, they are not particularly useful. Where/how are K and T defined?

Comment: @HenryTwist the String values & keys are instances of the hashmap `m` with generic type K & T. Thanks for responding. Apologies for the confusion & misunderstanding.